# No hot water in only one bath tub

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, bathtub, hot-water

[image: This is how the faucet is in one of the bath tub]

We are not getting hot water in only one bath tub. The left side is for hot water and right side is for cold. There is no drop in pressure when I turn on only the left side. But instead of hot water we just get cold water.

[image: Anti Scald valve under the sink opposite to the problematic tub]

Comment: There must be a hidden anti-scald thermostatic valve.  Is this a raised tub? Is there access from somewhere? Access panel? From below?

Comment: no it is not a raised tub and there is no access from behind. Unlike the faucets in the sink which has anti-scald value under them, I think bathtub doesn't have any such valve. Also, this problem started just recently

Comment: If I understand correctly, turning on the left or hot side only is causing water to cold water run (and it never gets hot), if that’s the case then there is a malfunctioning anti-scald valve somewhere.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you turn off the hot water at the water heater (there should be a valve), what happens when you try the "hot" side of the problematic tub, and the "hot" side of the other tubs/sinks?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @DanielGriscom when I turn off hot water valve from the control panel I get no hot water in sinks. In the problematic tub I just get cold water from hot side.

Comment: I think @Tyson is right. It may be caused by antiscald valve malfunction. Under the sink opposite to the problematic bathtub I see an antiscald valve. I have attached the picture for the same. Previously I thought it is for sink. But I think it is for the bathtub. The valve is jammed, I can't turn it. May be there is some clogging there or the valve itself has gone bad